# Rotate a Marker in OSMDroid for Android?

Tags: java, android, maps, openstreetmap, osmdroid

Ok, this one has been bugging me for hours, I have the following relatively simple code that places a marker on a osmdroid map

```
final ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
OverlayItem marker = new OverlayItem("markerTitle", "markerDescription", new GeoPoint(52.033954,1.210179));
marker.setMarkerHotspot(OverlayItem.HotspotPlace.TOP_CENTER);
items.add(marker);

Drawable newMarker = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.maincar);
DefaultResourceProxyImpl resProxyImp = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());
ItemizedIconOverlay markersOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(items, newMarker, null, resProxyImp);
mapView.getOverlays().add(markersOverlay);
```

However the marker is always facing the top of the screen (0deg reotation). How can I go about easily rotating each marker to a specified degree (360deg being a full circle)?

Comment: Consider giving the bounty to the one whom answered your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try use **RotateMyBitmap** method like this:

```
Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

Bitmap target = RotateMyBitmap(source, 120.0f);

final ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
OverlayItem marker = new OverlayItem("markerTitle", "markerDescription", new GeoPoint(52.033954,1.210179));
marker.setMarkerHotspot(OverlayItem.HotspotPlace.TOP_CENTER);
items.add(marker);

Drawable newMarker = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), target);

//Drawable newMarker = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.maincar);
DefaultResourceProxyImpl resProxyImp = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());
ItemizedIconOverlay markersOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(items, newMarker, null, resProxyImp);
mapView.getOverlays().add(markersOverlay);
```

Where **RotateMyBitmap** is:

```
public static Bitmap RotateMyBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle)
{
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

Result is:

[image]

This works fine but I recommend you use [MyLocationOverlay](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/MyLocationOverlay.java) class

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to add any custom code, you can also replace your `ItemizedIconOverlay` by a Marker from [OSMBonusPack library](http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack) (on top of osmdroid).

It supports `setRotation(degreees)`.

It also supports "flat" or "billboard" modes, depending on what you want to happen if the map is also rotated.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
Bitmap bmpOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.maincar_osm);
Bitmap bmResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpOriginal.getWidth()*2, bmpOriginal.getHeight()*2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(bmResult);
tempCanvas.rotate(270, bmpOriginal.getWidth()/2, bmpOriginal.getHeight()/2);
tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, null);
Drawable newMarker = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bmResult);
DefaultResourceProxyImpl resProxyImp = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());
ItemizedIconOverlay markersOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(items, newMarker, null, resProxyImp);
mapView.getOverlays().add(markersOverlay);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to create a subclass of ItemizedItemOverlay. Override the onDrawItem() and try something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDrawItem(ISafeCanvas canvas, Item item, Point curScreenCoords, float aMapOrientation) {

    int degrees = 90;
    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(degrees, curScreenCoords.x, curScreenCoords.y);
    super.onDrawItem(canvas, item, curScreenCoords, aMapOrientation);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this: only if you need rotating the camera

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(centerCoordinates)      // Sets the center of the map
                .zoom(zoom)                   // Sets the zoom
                .bearing(bearing)             // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder

googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is for a Google Map rather than OSM and rotates the whole map rather then just the marker. Thanks for at least answering though :-)